# Are Honda and Toyota o-rings all metric?

Tags: honda, toyota, measurement

I work mainly on Hondas and Toyotas. I think all the bolts I've accessed have been metric.

Is it safe to assume that all o-rings used on these vehicles are metric sizes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, but not for certain.

Manufacturers build cars in many countries, and sometimes or often source parts and assemblies from other countries. Without knowing what specific parts and assemblies and other products join to feed a particular assembly line, the question cannot be answered.

But because Honda and Toyotas are generally designed in Japan, it's a reasonable assumption that o-rings are metric.